# text in text editors gets scrambled after defining set_prompt

Tags: linux, bash

I've set `set_prompt` to print prompt always on a new line.

```
set_prompt() {
   local curpos
   stty -echo
   while read -t 0; do :; done
   echo -en "\033[6n"
   IFS=';' read -s -d R -a curpos
   stty echo
   (( curpos[1] > 1 )) && printf "\n"
}
```

but now, if I edit a file in text editors like `emacs` or `nano`, the text gets scrambled like printing character at wrong place or cursor jumps ahead or back while navigating, making text overlap.

Comment: I just tested your code (together with `PROMPT_COMMAND='set_prompt'` to [actually make it do something](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106281)) on bash 3.2.57 on MacOS, and cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. I suspect it's caused either by some peculiarity of your system or some part of your bash settings _other than_ the code you've shown us above.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen i've posted `PS1` i'm using at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496849/text-in-text-editors-gets-scrambled-after-defining-set-prompt?noredirect=1#comment914038_496849. stackoverflow is closing my question.